# Entity Framework 1 to many Scaffolding

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have:

Database tables: Region, Muscle

A Region is a region on the human body (e.g. Chest)
A Muscle is a muscle on the human body (e.g. Deltoids)

A Muscle has a RegoinId as foreignKey.

Here is the model classes:

```
public class Region
{
    [Key]
    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    public string RegionName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Muscle> Muscles { get; set; }
}

    public class Muscle
{
    [Key]
    public int MuscleId { get; set; }
    public string LatinName { get; set; }
    public string DkName { get; set; }
    public string EnName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    public Region Region { get; set; }
}
```

I then scaffolded a RegionsController with the following method:

```
// GET: api/Regions
    public IQueryable<Region> GetRegions()
    {
        return db.Regions;
    }
```

This works fine, but the Muscles property of the region is null.

So can i somehow tell Entity Framework to automatically include a regions muscles, when scaffolding the controller class?

If that is too much dreaming, how can i then include the muscles myself?

I tried the following without luck:

```
var regions = db.Regions.ForEachAsync(r => r.Muscles = db.Muscles.Where(m => m.RegionId == r.RegionId));
```

Complaining since r.Muscles is an ICollection and db.Muscles is of type IQueryable.

So please, what are my options and best practises for getting out my regions with their corresponding muscles.

(if it means anything to the solution, my end goal is to return json for my angularJS app)

Regards, a stuck programmer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you query the Regions, Include `Muscles` as well.

```
return db.Regions.Include(s=>s.Muscles)
```

[`Include`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx) method include the related objects specified in the include clause in the query results.

Comment: Ok that was almost too easy.

Comment: But can i tell EF to do this for me?

Answer (score 3):

If this is Code first, you need to add virtual to the Region property to get the values loaded from the database.

```
public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
```

To include all muscles from all regions, you can do it in the following way:

```
var musclesWithRegions = db.Regions.Include(r => r.Muscles).ToList();
```

Keep in mind that this query will get all the rows in the two tables, which can be slow depending on data. You may need to filter them with Where.